# Preventing MITM in System.Net.Sockets Server-Client

Tags: .net, security, tcp, client-server

I have a TCP listener that works as a server and TCP Client that connects to that server and shares crucial information that i really would not like to be leaked by MITM (Man in the Middle Attack)

**My question (ITS VERY CLEAR) How could i make sure the my clients are connected to my servers and not to any other fake server**[So i make sure that the attacker did not make a fake server and uses the client without paying for an account]

**NOTE:** AS i told in the beginning i am not using webservice , its only a Socket Listener that Listens for all client connections

*I was told to use SSLStream with certificate but there is not good documentation for this one so is there any way to achieve what i want , or any good [BASIC] documentation for SSLStream using certification*

Answer (score 1):

Its simple - you use SSL. This is a tried and true technology in use all over the internet and private networks.

The key is to validate that the certificate the server presents is a certificate you trust.

The first step is to produce a listening socket SSL, and give the socket a certificate. Check that clients can connect to that, and that SSL sessions are being established. After that, you can implement the validation callback in the SSLStream class to check that the certificate the server presents is the one you expect.

Comment: Excuse me your post is good but its not giving any references or any beneficial things , as i said i need any BASIC tutorial to teach me how could i achieve all of that

Comment: Where is the professionals here please i need help my whole project is for that point ! i want to prevent the FAKE SERVER , in other word [Make sure that my client is connected to my TCP Listener THE [SERVER]